# Linux bash command incorrectly handles zeros in output.

Tags: linux, bash, x11

I'm using Debian 6-64.
When i'm running a command

```
echo -n `cat /proc/$(ps -o pid --no-header -C x-session-manager | tr -d ' ')/environ 2>/dev/null | tr '\0000' '\n'|grep XA|cut -d '=' -f 2`
```

to acquire XAUTHORITY for the current user logged in, I expect it to return at the moment my actual xauthority path, which is:

```
/var/run/gdm3/auth-for-alex-g5t0xM
```

but what it actually returns is

```
/var/run/gdm3/auth-for-alex-g5t
```

the part `0xM` is missing.

Apparently it somehow takes `0` as `'\0'`, truncating the output.

What can I do to receive the correct output?

Answer (score 4):

`tr` manual:

```
\NNN   character with octal value NNN (1 to 3 octal digits)
```

You've given four digits. Fourth one handled as separate symbol (`'0'`) and gets replaced too.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to 3 and got the correct result. I should have looked into the manual.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well and is a little more concise:

```
tr '\000' '\n' </proc/$(pgrep x-session-manager)/environ | awk -F= '/XAUTHORITY/{print $2}'
```